# Overlapping IP in subnetting

Tags: networking, router, ip

I am doing a network in packet tracer. I use the subnetting in my network. The subnetting is work on first router but, when i am going to next it warns the ip overlapping. Here's the network as below

First Range 192.168.1.0 /28 255.255.255.240
2nd   Range 192.168.1.16 /30 255.255.255.252
3rd   Range 192.168.1.20 /28 255.255.255.240

I used the 4 routers 4 switch & 8 pc's each.
On the 2nd router i got the warning 
192.168.1.16 overlaps with Serial0/1/0
The above serial is on 2nd router and this warning is given on Interface g0/0. I am using the ip is 192.168.1.21 255.255.255.240.When I use this it warns and it doesnt take the ip. I used the 2nd range for connecting two router but it doesnt take range as 2 hosts.Whenever i set the 192.168.1.33 it takes as ip

help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your second and third ranges overlap. The way to do this is to convert the IP addresses and masks to binary (all IP addresses are simply 32-bit binary numbers), and mask the addresses with the mask by performing a logical `AND`. If any have the same result, then they are overlapping networks.

```
192.168.1.16    is 11000110101010000000000100010000
255.255.255.252 is 11111111111111111111111111111100
               AND ===================================
                   11000110101010000000000100010000 = 192.168.1.16

192.168.1.20    is 11000110101010000000000100010100
255.255.255.240 is 11111111111111111111111111110000
               AND ===================================
                   11000110101010000000000100010000 = 192.168.1.16
```

As you can see, the networks for those two addresses are the same network. There is an [excellent answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) on the [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) site that explains all this.